# Cannot install xts package for R on Mac OS

Tags: r, macos, fortran, clang, xts

I need to install xts to run the forecast package. The error looks to have something to do with gfortran not "supporting" a "directive" named ".stabs". The gfortran compiler I installed [via the pkg file on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools), clang4 is installed via the [package provided here](https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-clang)

Here is the (abridged) output from RStudio:

```
> install.packages('xts')

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
    binary source needs_compilation
xts 0.10-0 0.10-1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘xts’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xts_0.10-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 524633 bytes (512 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 512 KB

* installing *source* package ‘xts’ ...
** package ‘xts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c add_class.c -o add_class.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c any.c -o any.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c attr.c -o attr.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c binsearch.c -o binsearch.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c coredata.c -o coredata.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c diff.c -o diff.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c dimnames.c -o dimnames.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c leadingNA.c -o leadingNA.o
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/zoo/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c merge.c -o merge.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c period.max.f -o period.max.o
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:1:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "/private/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T/RtmpumHSCA/R.INSTALL4c1e7561eb52/xts/src/",100,0,7,Ltext0
            ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:2:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "period.max.f",100,0,7,Ltext0
            ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:5:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "gcc2_compiled.",60,0,0,0
            ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:9:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,12
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:19:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,12
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:29:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,34
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:33:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,12
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:36:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,34
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:47:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,38
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:68:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,42
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:73:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,38
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:80:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,39
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:85:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,42
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:88:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,38
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:90:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,39
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:92:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,38
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:101:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,49
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:105:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabd  68,0,34
    ^
 ...

 /var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:140:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "j:r(0,4)",64,0,24,0
            ^
 /var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:141:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabn  192,0,0,LBB2
    ^
 /var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:142:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabn  224,0,0,LBE2
    ^
 /var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:143:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "pos:(0,4)",128,0,25,-12
            ^
 /var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:144:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "j:r(0,4)",64,0,24,0
            ^
 /var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:145:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabn  192,0,0,LBB10
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:146:2: error: unknown directive
    .stabn  224,0,0,LBE10
    ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:148:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "",36,0,0,Lscope1-LFBB1
            ^
/var/folders/y1/7zsj8_x973n4xjwg5gg6s53jr4zz65/T//ccwtKwZR.s:149:9: error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
    .stabs  "",100,0,0,Letext0
            ^
make: *** [period.max.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xts’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/xts’
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘xts’ had non-zero exit status
```

e: I found my solution here: http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/

Comment: What's the output of `gfortran -###` ? You're somehow getting a compiler that's generating ancient assembly directives.

Comment: `bash$ gfortran -###
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin8
Configured with: /Builds/unix/gcc/gcc-4.2/configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/share/man --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --build=i686-apple-darwin8 --host=i686-apple-darwin8 --target=i686-apple-darwin8 --enable-languages=fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.3`

Comment: An old gfortran like that may need the `-gdwarf-2` option instead of `-g`. I don't know where  `install.packages` gets its Makefile from (https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xts_0.10-1.tar.gz doesn't have one for the source code) so I'm not sure of the location of the Makefile you'd need to modify.

Comment: Ok, I thought I had an updated gfortran because I downloaded the package from CRAN but apparently that package is pretty old. I downloaded the newest version from the gfortran website and added the following line to my ~/.R/Makevars file: `FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/6.3.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm` . This seems to have resolved my problem